# Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra and $J$ maximal ideal of $A$. Why is $\overline{J}$ an ideal of $A$?

Tags: banach-algebras, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra with maximal ideal $J$.

Why is it true that $\overline{J}$ is also an ideal of $A$, i.e. the closure of a maximal ideal of $A$ is an ideal of $A$?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $\overline{J}$ is an ideal follows from the continuity of the algebraic operations. For example, if $x \in \overline{J}$ and $y \in A$ then we can choose $x_n \in J$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ and then $yx_n \rightarrow yx$ and since $J$ is an ideal, $yx_n \in J$ and so $yx \in \overline{J}$. Similarly for right multiplication and addition. The interesting thing is that if $J$ is a proper ideal, then $\overline{J}$ must also be a **proper** ideal. This implies for example that a maximal ideal of $A$ must be closed.

Comment: Thank you! :). I was actually needing this in my proof to show that $J$ is closed :). I needed $\overline{J}$ to be an ideal to use maximality of $J$ to deduce that $J = \overline{J}$ :)

Comment: Note that it is not enough to show that $\overline{J}$ is an ideal - you must also show that $\overline{J}$ is a **proper** ideal. Otherwise, the fact that $J \subseteq \overline{J}$ and $J$ is maximal won't imply that $J = \overline{J}$.

Comment: Thank you :). I did manage to show that it is a proper ideal :). This follows from that $J \subseteq \overline{J} \subseteq A\setminus A_i$ Where $A_i$ is the set of invertible elements of $A$. But since $A$ is unital, $A_i \neq \emptyset$ and therefore $\overline{J} \neq A$, i.e. It is a proper ideal :). We may then use maximality principle to get the condition for closed :).